# Unable to run the multichain-node (npm module) in client side(browser)

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

```
let multichain = require("multichain-node")({
    port: 6001,
    host:'localhost',
    user:'myuser',
    pass:'mypassword'
    });

    multichain.getInfo((error,info) => {
    if(error){
    throw error;
    }
    console.log(info);
    })
output:version: '1.0',
  nodeversion: 10000901,
  protocolversion: 10008,
  chainname: 'chain1',
  description: 'chain1',
  protocol: 'multichain',
  port: 6001,
  setupblocks: 60,
  nodeaddress: 'mulmul@localhost:6001',
  burnaddress: '1XXXXXXWh4XXXXXXXyXXXXXXZdXXXXXXYjGhfn',
  incomingpaused: false,
  miningpaused: false,
  walletversion: 60000,
  balance: 0,
  walletdbversion: 2,
  reindex: false,
  blocks: 127,
  timeoffset: 0,
  connections: 0,
  proxy: '',
  difficulty: 6e-8,
  testnet: false,
  keypoololdest: 1506490805,
  keypoolsize: 2,
  paytxfee: 0,
  relayfee: 0,
  errors: '' }
```

this output displayed in command prompt, How can i execute this code in browser

Comment: what are you want to do, this code not suitable for browsers And in my mind, multichain just work for servers

Answer (score 0):

`multichain-node` is a node module; it doesn't make sense to run it in the browser.

In particular it uses node's http module to make http requests; if you wanted to do that in the browser you'd need to use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` to do that, and you would need CORS to be set up correctly.

Comment: how to fetch it, can you give detailed explanation

Comment: used browserify to bundle the all js files, and run it on browser then i got ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE